# Capture Outgoing Email to One Mailbox or Account on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, email, smtp

I am looking to see if anything exists that would allow us to capture all outgoing email on a machine -- for example, in a staging environment -- and drop it in a single place, which ideally would be something we could check with a mail client.

Currently we're doing this on the software level (if environment is staging, rewrite address) which is a bit ugly and leads to errors.

The servers are currently on Debian Linux, using exim as the mail transport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy it, add an additional transport which writes the data where you want it.  You have a choice of formats: mbox, Maildir, BSMTP, and other.  Add this as a shadow transport to the appropriate transports.  You may want to use a router to select a custom transport with the shadow transport defined.

If you just want to capture the mail use a router to select an new or existing transport to save the output as above.

Adding routers and transports may be easier to implement using a split configuration.  This will be stable over upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you are using exim, but you may want to consider a switch to postfix for this.  Postfix has an `always_bcc` configuration setting that makes this super simple.  Details in the [postfix faq](http://www.seaglass.com/postfix/faq.html#svmsg).